# .gitignore syntax - how to exclude virtualenv sub-directories?

Tags: syntax, virtualenv, gitignore

I have a couple different virtual environments in a project, e.g.

`~/project_dir/sub_dirs/venv/...`

Adding `*/venv/*` to the .gitignore file does not prevent the virtual environment folders and their contents from being excluded. What is the correct syntax to prevent these virtual environment directories from being added to the git repository?

Comment: Is this question about how to ignore or about how to stop ignoring those directories?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

per https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore

`venv/` does the trick for sub-directories.

Comment: Does this one work for any `venv` directory? Mine named `tmp_env` and it can't be ignored by this file, I still have to manually ignore it.

Comment: you have to add `tmp_env/` in your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 7):

1. Create in your current project's folder ".gitignore" file
2. For example, if you have some folders as "venv" and ".vscode" than you just add their names in ".gitignore" file:
   venv/
   .vscode/

Answer (score 1):

If in Visual Studio, you can simple click in **Team Explore -> right button in folder -> ignore**

[image]

Comment: use this way but on pycharm and I found out that I fill wrong `.venv` instead `/venv/` !!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the .gitignore folder just add the name of the folder with a slash at the end.

Example: venv/

This will ignore all sub directories in the venv folder.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything to get this ignore to work, until I realized the easiest solution to this problem. Set up my virtual environment in a different directory outside the project!

Pycharm for example asks where you want to set up a virtual environment when you open a project with requirements. I just set it up outside in a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

I Had similar problem, But i'm trying to exclude 'vir-2.7/' which is not working.
Seems the '.'(dot) was interrupted differently by git, so i have changed the directory name to 'vir_2_7', to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My virtual env was named as -venv. I included *venv* in .gitignore and it worked